# In a Mirau Interferometer what is the distance between the mirror and the beamsplitter?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, interference, interferometry, microscopy

A Mirau interferometer (shown left in the figure, next to the Michelson configuration to the right) is an important instrument for non-contact surface profilometry.

Briefly, taken from Wikipedia, "at the beam splitter the source light is split into a reference path (reflected) and a sampling path (transmitted onto the sample). On the comparison face there is a mirrored circle in the middle. The two paths recombine to form an interference image."

[image]

"By changing the z position of the sample, interference images are acquired at a sequence of path (phase) differences: 0, λ/4, λ/2, and 3λ/4. These interference maps are functions of background intensity, fringe modulation, and phase. Three such images provide enough information to solve for the topographic image of a sample."

My question is (having found such an objective that is missing the beamsplitter and wanting to tinker) does it matter what the distance is between the mirrored circle and the beamsplitter?  My intuition is no, that it does not matter, however, my choices for potential distances could be pretty vast -- from 100s of nanometers to several millimeters.

The reason I think it does not matter is that as stated in the second paragraph, the objective is used by taking a series of images, translating in Z on the scale of the lights nanometer wavelength. This distance is merely a reference point from which the lens will be moved by one wavelength of light.

The reason I think it *might* matter is that the imaging objective does have a focal distance (7mm).  My foggy intuition in physics tells me I might need the distance to be 7mm. Is it possible that I should be thinking of the objective lens imaging the plane of the beamsplitter, and so to get a focused image I would want it to be the focal distance of the objective?

Comment: *. . . . does it matter what the distance is between the mirrored circle and the beam splitter?* - probably close to the distance between beam splitter and specimen surface?

Comment: I think that would be the equal path length case.  Then when the objective is moved, the path length between the mirror and beamsplitter remains constant, and the distance between the beamsplitter and specimen moves (by some fraction of the lights wavelength).  This results in a phase shift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reflective surface of the beam splitter should be exactly equidistant to the reflective surface of the mirror and the focal plane of the objective.
The higher the axial resolution the objective has the more sensitive this positioning will be.